# Python Pandas Datetime Custom BQuarterEnd

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to establish anchored business quarters ending on the last day of February, May, August, and October.

When I have any date in the specified quarter, I want to roll it forward to the end of the business quarter.

Examples:

```
pd.to_datetime('2017-11-15') + [custom business quarter] -> Timestamp('2018-02-28 00:00:00')
pd.to_datetime('2017-12-03') + [custom business quarter] -> Timestamp('2018-02-28 00:00:00')
pd.to_datetime('2018-03-03') + [custom business quarter] -> Timestamp('2018-05-31 00:00:00')
```

If I do the following:

```
pd.to_datetime('2017-11-15') + BQuarterEnd()
```

I get

```
 Timestamp('2017-12-29 00:00:00')
```

I have references that suggest I can incorporate month like `FEB` but I can't figure out how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.